# Distribute C++ application as .exe or .msi?

Tags: c++, windows, installation

I am looking for a program that can take the program I made in Visual C++ 2008 and distribute it in a mature installer for Windows. I want an application that is FREE (or trial).

---

The setup and deployment folder is not there when a select File-->Add-->New Project

Comment: "The setup made in Visual C++ is not good because it DOES NOT let you make a desktop icon, choose a directory to install" ... Yes it does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), which is free, but can be confusing because it's lots of scripts. That said, it *can* do anything you might want to do.

[Install Creator](http://www.clickteam.com/website/usa/installcreator.html) from ClickTeam is very simple to use and is my preferred application but it does cost money.

Comment: Unicode NSIS (http://www.scratchpaper.com/) should be used, ANSI is so last century.

Answer (score 5):

[WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) has a fairly steep learning curve, but it gives you full access to all features of Windows Installer, with no limitations. It's originally an Microsoft project, and is what Microsoft uses internally for many of its products. It's free and open source under the Common Public License (which permits its use in closed-source products without requiring you to license your own code under it).

Answer (score 5):

For a setup .exe I like [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), which will let you do desktop icons, amongst other things.  Basically you create an Inno Setup installer file which you can pass into the setup compiler which means you can also build it from the command-line.  They provide both a GUI and a command-line compiler.  The bundled documentation is also very complete.

For MSI you can try the [Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolset.](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), which is similar to Inno Setup in that you can compile from the command-line, but a certain amount of Windows Installer / MSI knowledge is expected.

Answer (score 4):

Use setup project in Visual Studio

Comment: I've used the setup project in VS which is fine for simple installers.  You can choose where to install and create shortcuts with icons (though I found that you need to create a separate .ico file and set that as the icon property).  I think it's the simplest and cheapest option.

Comment: Um, Setup Projects in VS 2008 seem to support the features Mohit is looking for--desktop icons, prompt for installation directory, etc.--you just have to dig around to find the options. (For example, for the desktop shortcut you have to drag the built-in one from the Start Menu to the Desktop folder to make a copy there too.)

Comment: I've never had any problems with setup projects in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following programs:

[Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)
[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

Don't forget to include [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/).  Free, open source and easy enough to make a simple installer in minutes while also supporting complex, scripted installers if you find you need them.